# Python3 - Convert enum to different datatypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, type-conversion, enumeration

I'm currently working with an enum of the following type:

```
class System(Enum):
  FIRST = 1
  SECOND = 2
```

Now I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
a = System.FIRST
url = a.getSystemURL()
```

where the url for the enumeration members `FIRST` and `SECOND` are different of course.

I could create a dictionary with the enumeration members as keys and the urls as values, but this won't assure that if I later add an enumeration member I'll remember to add corresponding the dictionary entry.

Is there a clean way to have an enumeration with multiple values for the enumeration members? And to name these different values?

Something like this:

```
class System(Enum):
  Values = (Value, url, something)
  FIRST = 1, 'https://www.example.com', 42
  SECOND = 2, 'https://www.test.com', 13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [an example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet) like this in the documentation. If the class defines an `__init__` method, the enum values will be passed to it as arguments. This means you can define your enum like so:

```
class System(Enum):
    FIRST = 1, 'https://www.example.com', 42
    SECOND = 2, 'https://www.test.com', 13

    def __init__(self, value, url, something):
        self.value_ = value
        self.url = url
        self.something = something
```

(Note that `value` is a special attribute reserved by enums, so I named the attribute `value_` to avoid a name clash.)

You can now access these attributes on each enum member:

```
>>> System.FIRST.url
'https://www.example.com'
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for! If I only use one property. Should I still add the `int`s to the definition? For the enum would you prefer just to put the `url` so `enum_mem.value` and `enum_mem.url` will give the same result?

Comment: @user9115052 I'd say it depends on your use case. Generally speaking, there's no need to have an integer associated with each enum value. But if you have a use for that integer in your program, go ahead and add it.

Answer (score 1):

Both the stdlib `Enum` and `aenum`<sup>1</sup> easily support your use case (although more work is required for the stdlib version).

---

`stdlib enum` 3.4+  (See the docs for [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-a-custom-new) and [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations) explanations.)

```
import enum
class System(enum.Enum):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

    def __init__(self, url, something):
        self.url = url
        self.something = something

    FIRST = 'https://www.example.com', 42
    SECOND = 'https://www.test.com', 13
```

---

`aenum` -- Usable for both Python 2 and 3 code.  `aenum` also makes a few things easier -- the above code would be:

```
import aenum
class System(aenum.AutoNumberEnum):
    _init_ = 'url something'
    FIRST = 'https://www.example.com', 42
    SECOND = 'https://www.test.com', 13
```

And in use:

```
--> System.FIRST
<System.First: 1>

--> System.FIRST.url
'https://www.example.com'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 0):

Make the values a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
from collections import namedtuple
from enum import Enum

Entry = namedtuple('Entry', ['value', 'url', 'something'])

class System(Enum):
  FIRST = Entry(1, 'https://www.example.com', 42)
  SECOND = Entry(2, 'https://www.test.com', 13)

print(System.FIRST.value.url)
# https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code you wrote? It already just works! Of course you don't *really* have multiple values, you have a single tuple value—but that isn't a problem:

```
>>> class System(Enum):
...     FIRST = 1, 'https://www.example.com', 42
...     SECOND = 2, 'https://www.test.com', 13
>>> _, url, _ = System.SECOND.value
>>> url
'https://www.example.com'
>>> a = System.FIRST
>>> url = a.value[1]
>>> url
'https://www.example.com'
```

There are things you can do to make this a little nicer, like using a `namedtuple` instead of a plain `tuple` so you can write `a.value.url` instead of `a.value[1]`, but you've already written something that works.